# RxJava debounce operator only showing the last emission on Android

Tags: android, reactive, debouncing

I'm trying to use RxJava on Android to emit a number after 1 second has passed.

However, only the last item (7) gets emitted.

What am I doing wrong?

```
private Observable<Integer> getIntegerObservable(){
    return Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
}

getIntegerObservable()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + String.valueOf(integer)+"\n");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The Debounce operator filters out items emitted by the source Observable that are rapidly followed by another emitted item.

In your case numbers 1 through 7 are all emitted within a second. 
The window specified for debounce is one second. The latest item emitted at the end of one second is 7 and so all the other items are filtered out and you receive 7 as output.

The following image shows a case where 6 items are emitted consecutively within one timeframe. Only the sixth item will pass and others will be filtered.
[image: Debounce for 6 items]

The following image shows another case where the 6th item is emitted after one timeframe so both 5th and 6th items are emitted while the others are filtered.
[image]

Hope this helps, try playing with the marble diagram at the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) site.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) says

> **Debounce** only emit an item from an Observable if a particular timespan has passed without it emitting another item. It filters out
>   items emitted by the source Observable that are rapidly followed by
>   another emitted item.

Since in your case all items are emitted within the time window. Only the latest item gets emmited and all the other items are filtered out.

I guess what you're looking for is [Delay](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html)

> The **Delay** operator modifies its source Observable by pausing for a
>   particular increment of time (that you specify) before emitting each
>   of the source Observable’s items. This has the effect of shifting the
>   entire sequence of items emitted by the Observable forward in time by
>   that specified increment.

**So instead it should look something like this:**

```
getIntegerObservable()
          .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(...);
```

You also should consider calling the `delay(..)` before the `subscribeOn(..)` to avoid blocking the main thread

Checkout this [article](https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a), it explains  the difference between `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`

**UPDATE**

You can wrap  [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) in an Obserable. For example:

```
Observable.create(emitter -> new CountDownTimer(7000, 1000) {

          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 emitter.onNext(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
           }

           public void onFinish() {
                emitter.onComplete();
           }
         }.start())
.doOnNext() //you can log your timer here
.subscribe(); //or here
```

**BONUS** (Just for fun :D)

RxJava looks way cooler with java8

```
Observable.create(this::startCountDownTimer)
       .doOnNext() //use long value
       .map(String::valueOf) //map to string
       .doOnNext() //use string value
       .doOnComplete() //gets called when the timer is up
       .subscribe(this::handleTick, this::handleError);
```

Count down method

```
private void startCountDownTimer(ObservableEmitter<Long> emitter) {
    new CountDownTimer(7000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            emitter.onNext(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            emitter.onComplete();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Handle Ticking method

```
private void handleTick(String timer) {
    //Update UI
}
```

Handle error method

```
private void handleError(Throwable t) {
    //Log and inform user
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work the way I want, it waits for that time interval then it emits all at once